# Add double quotes to items of a comma separated list

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I would like to add double quotes a directory full of files inplace. The transformation will be like below:

`INSERT INTO %T (colA, colB)`  changes to `INSERT INTO %T ("colA", "colB")`

I have tried various examples using `sed`. I was able to get `grep` to identify the files and line numbers. Can you show me how to achieve this inplace without manually modifying the files?

Comment: how many parameters exists inside `(..)`?

Comment: There could be any number of colX inside.

Comment: To complement @AvinashRaj question: is there only one group of `()`, if not should all the parameters inside be quoted or not ?

Answer (score 1):

This may do:

```
awk -F"[()]" '{n=split($(NF-1),a,", *");for (i=1;i<n;i++) s=s sprintf("\"%s\", ",a[i]);s=s "\""a[n]"\"";print $1 "("s")"}'
```

eks:

```
echo 'INSERT INTO %T (colA, colB, colC)' | awk -F"[()]" '{n=split($(NF-1),a,", *");for (i=1;i<n;i++) s=s sprintf("\"%s\", ",a[i]);s=s "\""a[n]"\"";print $1 "("s")"}'
INSERT INTO %T ("colA", "colB", "colC")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '
# Filter to insert only
   /INSERT INTO/ !b
# Add first and last " inside ()
   s/(/("/
   s/)[^)]*$/")/
# add all internal " around each ,
   s/,[[:space:]]*/","/g
' YourFile
```

Onliner version (without filter and assuming space char as *space*):

```
sed 's/(/("/;s/)[^)]*$/")/;s/, */","/g' YourFile
```

- Self explain.
- Assume there structure is without internal `()` and only 1 group of `()`

Comment: Oh, damn. You're right, isolating isn't even necessary in this case. Mind you, I'd exclude spaces around the identifier list and on both sides of the commas, as in `sed 's/(\s*/&"/; s/\s*)/"&/; s/\s*,\s*/"&"/g'`.

Comment: to be exact, i try nearly same way as you and when i put back the isolated part, i see that it is only needed if other `()` occur inside the main `()`, so assuming there are not, it become useless to isolate. Your code still very usefull if argument inside are more complex

Comment: You mean it's more useful if the code *outside* the argument list is more complex (if it might be affected by the transformations). If the argument list itself is more complex, you'll still have the complexity after you isolated it. Anyway: There are contexts when the trick I used is useful, but I didn't see that this wasn't one of them.

Comment: both in fact. The internal complexity could be easier to treat when isolated from outside (mainly for the regex construction) and could allow (by exemple) function with `()`. Anyway, it depend on request and constraint :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another way with awk

```
awk -F"(" -vOFS="(" '{gsub(/[^, )]+/,"\"&\"",$2)}1' file
```

---

#### Output

```
INSERT INTO %T ("colA", "colB")
```